# Error in pointer allocation for a binary search tree

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to create a binary tree using C++ classes and pointers. The tree is being initialized properly. However, when I add nodes to the tree, instead of adding them to the left or right sub-tree, the root node gets overwritten. I tried printing the inorder value to check if the nodes are added correctly or not, but that also prints nothing.
Here is the code for the same.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    
    private:
        Node *left;
        Node *right;

    public:
        int number;
    
    Node(int number){
        this->number = number;
        this->left = NULL;
        this->right = NULL;
    }

    void set_left_node(Node *node){
        this->left = node;
    }
    void set_right_node(Node *node){
        this->right = node;
    }
    Node* read_left_node(){
        return this->left; 
    }
    Node* read_right_node(){
        return this->right;
    }
    
};

class Binary_Tree{
    public:
        Node *root;
    
    Binary_Tree(){
        this->root = NULL;
    }
    Node* read_root(){
        return this->root;
    }
    
    Node* insert_node(Node *root, Node node){
        
        if(!root){
            root = &node;
            cout << "Inserted " << node.number << " " << root << endl; 
            return root;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Root and node values " << root->number << " " << node.number << endl;
            if(root->number < node.number){
                root->set_right_node(insert_node(root->read_right_node(), node));
            }
            else{
                root->set_left_node(insert_node(root->read_left_node(), node));
            }
        }

        return root;
    }
    void inorder(Node *root){
        if (root != NULL){
            
            inorder(root->read_left_node());
            cout<<root->number<<" ";
            inorder(root->read_right_node());
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    Binary_Tree bt = Binary_Tree();

    bt.root = bt.insert_node(bt.root, Node(34)); 
    bt.root = bt.insert_node(bt.root, Node(17));
    bt.root = bt.insert_node(bt.root, Node(56));

    cout << "Inorder" << endl;
    bt.inorder(bt.root);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image: of the code]

Comment: It's not advisable for `insert_node` to take a parameter named `root` when there is a class member with that same name and spelling. At best it's plain confusing, at worst it's a bug that may be contributing to your problem.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't ignore the compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/G6dPY9q33

Comment: The problem here arises due to call by reference. Check out the the main function, while calling the insert_node function, a direct call is made to the constructor of the Node class. This call to the constructor of Node class overwrites at the same location where the 1st object was stored instead of allocating a new memory location. For eg:- Node(34) is the root node after the first call, but after the 2nd call, the memory location of Node(34) is rewritten to Node(17) and the root node now points to Node(17).